# Transaction behavior for http fetch calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, transactions, fetch

Is there a way to create transactions for a group of http calls in javascript?

I am working with the popular Music APIs and I have a series of http calls I want to happen as a transaction, i.e. (All or nothing).

For example, I create a playlist, then I add songs to the playlist. Both actions cannot be done with one request, hence the need for multiple request. However, in a situation where creating playlist works but adding the songs to the playlist fail, I wouldn't want the playlist created in the first step to persist hence the need to group both calls in a transaction where they all pass or nothing happens.

In the above scenario, when retries occur, a new playlist with the same name is created to put the songs. This leads to duplicated playlists with the same name but different information (some empty and some with songs).

Comment: Sounds like you simply need to check if a playlist already exists before duplicating it or if possible set the field constraints for playlist to be unique depending on where they are being stored

Comment: Two playlists can have the same name so that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you suggest doesn't exist as an out-of-the-box solution. The best way would be if the API you're using offers something like this. For example, it *could* be possible to achieve something similar with a GraphQL query, provided there is one.

Otherwise, you'll have to program this behaviour on your own. E.g. let the user name the playlist and add songs. Upon submitting, you first try to create the playlist. If that succeeds, you continue adding songs. If at some point, a song addition didn't work, you re-delete the playlist. The net effect is that you have something like a *playlist transaction*.